# How to fix "Game Crush because of java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION "?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, logging, release

After I uploaded my game to the Play Store my game crashed on a device showing `java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION` The game is developed on **Unity Version: 2018.3.0f2**.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [Thread-296]
Unity version     : 2018.3.0f2
Device model      : samsung SM-J600FN
Device fingerprint: samsung/j6ltexx/j6lte:9/PPR1.180610.011/J600FNXXU3BSD2:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at ly.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290003@20290003.249178941.249178941:2)
  at lx.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290003@20290003.249178941.249178941:1)
  at lz.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290003@20290003.249178941.249178941:29)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.aq.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290003@20290003.249178941.249178941:10)
  at lc.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290003@20290003.249178941.249178941:8)
  at lc.run (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20290003@20290003.249178941.249178941:2)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at ab.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@17455079@17.4.55 (100306-248795830):4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.something.something"
    android:value="something"/>

    <activity 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"    
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

  </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: You have Admob in the app right? It seems to be caused by Ads you have in the app. Sometimes video ads failing to load can cause this kind of ANRs

Comment: Tnq for your answer.. Is there a way to fix it..?

Comment: What is your android api version?

Comment: And hope that you have already added the appID metadata to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Api version :4.1 or up.......... Adding AndroidManifest.xml on question. plz kindly see if everything is ok..

Comment: Please put your app level build.gradle as well here.

Comment: i am using unity default gradle .. did not modified anything. added it on question. so plz help.

Comment: plz help .. its really important for me

Comment: Not the project level build.gradle, the app level build.gradle is needed

Comment: sorry i dont have one.. i will add one in my app

Comment: [tag:CRUSH] is an acronym for Controlled Replication Under Scalable Hashing. It is the algorithm that drives the Ceph object storage environment.  it doesn't seem to apply here.  For the record, it's "Crash", not "Crush"